# C - Is it bad practice to use the same name for a function parameter, as the function itself?

Tags: c

e.g.

```
int send_fd(int fd, int send_fd);
```

I don't believe there's anything technically wrong with this (as the function name resides in a different scope), but is this considered bad practice?

I sometimes see code do something like this instead (i.e. omit the underscore / make a slight change to avoid using the same name):

```
int send_fd(int fd, int sendfd);
```

This seems inconsistent to me though / bothers me for some reason (naming stuff really brings out the OCD in me).

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  It's a bad practice.  It looks awkward on the declaration. Within the definition itself, it looks even more awkward.  Also prevents recursion.

Comment: I say it's terrible to use the same name (it makes it harder to reason about **what** `send_fd` you're referring to), and I would recommend something more *descriptive* - `int send_fd(int from_fd, int to_fd);`

Comment: You should always enable shadowing warnings so the compiler will warn about this. The actual question is: why would one want this? Function names and variable names should use self-explaining names. Using common sense, they cannot have the same names, because functions are typically verbs (or contain them) and variables are nouns or adjectives, depending on usage..

Comment: If *style* is the only aspect of this question, then *it is bad practice to ask "Is it bad practice to _____?" questions*... The answer is *always*: Does it make the code simpler or more maintainable than alternatives? If so, go for it, even if common advice is to the contrary (e.g. `goto` is an example of grossly underestimated functionality).

Comment: @Olaf 1/ There's no such thing as "common" "sense". 2/ Why can they not have the same names? Does the C standard state this? Or is it just your opinion? 3/ There are *hundreds* of English words that are both nouns and verbs. In fact, we use many of them commonly in programming: access, address, alert, break, call, catch, control, count, decay, decrease, delay, display, design, double, dump, echo, *email*, escape, float, flow, function, handle, jump, lock, lead, load, raise, record, reply, report, request, sign, signal, switch, test, tick, time, trace, track, type, use, watch, wrap and yield...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the info / suggestions. I actually didn't realize it prevented recursion (which would be a technical reason to avoid it). I'll stick to different / more descriptive names, unless I have a definitive reason not to.

Comment: @Seb: Feel free to write another essay about properly naming functions and variables in C. Maybe you understand my comment was a short excerpt of good practice. Which very well exists. About common sense: you proved me wrong about its existence, I really should not expect it (here). I beg your pardon. I really thought my comment was clear it is not a matter of the standard - why else would shadowing require enabling a warning?

Comment: *"I really thought my comment was clear it is not a matter of the standard - why else would shadowing require enabling a warning?"* [*"... If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope."*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one reason I would consider it as a bad practice is readability and maintainability. If you handed off this piece of code to a coworker, would they readily be able to identify what the difference is between the parameter and the function name? It would be a bit confusing at first glance. It is not technically wrong, but I would aim to make your code as readable as possible. Just looking at the function prototype of `int send_fd(int fd, int sendfd);`, I would have no idea what this function does. I think the function names and parameters should be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I ask because I've been running into similar naming / prototypes in embedded Linux / system programming, which seems to deviate from more traditional naming conventions (names are typically very short / generic / non-descriptive). I've been trying to follow a similar style / naming convention for consistency, but as you mention, they can indeed be a bit confusing.